# Extend C# code with XML Code

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I got some inspriation from the link "http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/146237/Reading-XML-documents-using-LINQ".

If I need to retrieve the data of `Subject1` and `Subject2`, how should the new c# be by replacing this code `listBox1.Items.Add(b.Element("Subject").Value.Trim());`

C#:

```
var books = from nodes in System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Load("Books.xml").Elements("Book") select nodes;

if (books != null)
{
    foreach (var b in books)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(b.Element("Subject").Value.Trim());

    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Books>
  <Book>
    <Subject>
    <Subject1>Subject1a</Subject1>
    <Subject2>Subject1a</Subject2>
    </Subject>
    <Content>
      History,Geography
    </Content>
  </Book>

  <Book>
    <Subject>
    <Subject1>Subject2b</Subject1>
    <Subject2>Subject2b</Subject2>
    </Subject>
    <Content>
      Biology,Chemistry,Physics
    </Content>
  </Book>
</Books>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, what about

```
foreach (var b in books) {
    var s = b.Element("Subject");
    listBox1.Items.Add(s.Element("Subject1").Value.Trim());
    listBox1.Items.Add(s.Element("Subject1").Value.Trim());
}
```

Comment: Subject1 & 2 are not direct children of Book, but descendants

Answer (score 0):

```
var items = (from node in System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse(xml).Elements("Book")
                     let subject = node.Element("Subject")
                     select new
                     {
                         Subject1 = subject.Element("Subject1"),
                         Subject2 = subject.Element("Subject2")

                     }).ToList();
```